# Jquery Mobile data-placeholder on dynamic select

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a select list dynamically and cant able to display the data-placeholder.  Here is the code I am using

```
var placeholder_flag = 1;
$.each(group_list, function(ctr, obj) {
  if(placeholder_flag){
    $('#bk_groupids').append('<option value="" data-placeholder="true">Select Group</option>');
      $("#bk_groupids").selectmenu('refresh', true);
      placeholder_flag = 0;
    }
    $('#bk_groupids').append('<option value='+obj.groupid+'>'+obj.groupname+'</option>');
    $("#bk_groupids").selectmenu('refresh', true);
});
```

group_list is an object array containing groupid and group name.

This is the HTML code

```
<select name="bk_groupids" id="bk_groupids" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

When I loaded into my android mobile it shows 'Select Group' as one of the option and it doesnt show as a placeholder.  Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  I need to set like below by turn off the native menu

```
<select name="bk_groupids" id="bk_groupids" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"></select>
```